# Cost of array lists

Tags: java, arrays, performance, arraylist

I know that to find the number of stores needed for n elements to be appended to a list when the size is doubled can be found by the summation `∑ from n=1 to log(2,n) of 2^n = 2n-1`.
My question is how I could use a summation to find a formula for when instead of doubling in size the list grows by exactly 2000 elements each time it grows?

Answer (score 0):

So, if array increases by 2000 elements, then n-sized array will increase `floor(n/2000)` times. As we may notice, last 2000 elements of it move at most once, next 2000-slot (from the end) moves twice, next 2000-slot (from the end) moves three times, and so on. So we have this formula:

```
∑ i = 1 to floor(n/2000)[ i * 2000 ] = 

2000 * (∑ i = 1 to floor(n/2000) [ i ]) =

2000 * (1 + 2 + 3 + .. + floor(n/2000)) =

2000 * (floor(n/2000)*(1 + floor(n/2000))/2)
```