# Time Complexity of Memory Allocation for an Array (not dynamic)

Tags: java, arrays, time-complexity

if i do this

```
int n = some arbitrary number
int[] array = new int[n];
```

is the time needed linear (O(n)) or constant (O(1))?
i looked [in the javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) and eg. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28014541/calculating-time-complexity-of-a-dynamic-array) in StackOverflow but didn't find an answer because all the posts i saw deal with dynamic allocation.

Comment: you may check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5640850/java-whats-the-big-o-time-of-declaring-an-array-of-size-n

Comment: i just didn't find it before ... should i delete the question (its a duplicate after all)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In java, when you create a new array of `int`, all members of the array must get the initial value for int (which is '0'), so the initialization includes `n` assignments of the value `0`, thus taking O(n).

You can also verify it, using the following code, with different n's:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int n = 1000000;
    int numSamples = 10000;
    long sumTime = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < numSamples; i++)
    {
        sumTime += test(n);
    }
    double average = sumTime / (double) numSamples;
    System.out.println(average);
}

private static long test(int size)
{
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    int[] a = new int[size];
    return System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
}
```

Comment: But OP says 'not dynamic' so maybe the compiler does it since s/he doesn't show the 'static' keyword, or perhaps the class loader - just speculating.

Comment: Test verifies that it's O(n). Added sample test code.